# Why does this 7th-level spellcaster NPC only have slots and prepared spells appropriate to a 3rd-level spellcaster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, published-adventures, npc, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

In *Tyranny of Dragons*, on page 184, an NPC stat block makes no sense. I’ve checked the errata and have found no correction.

> The stat block is for Dralmorrer Borngray.

It says the NPC “is a 7th-level spellcaster that uses Intelligence as his spellcasting ability” and has spells “prepared from the wizard spell list.” However, the spells prepared only go up to 2nd level and he has the spell slots appropriate to a 3rd-level spellcaster.

Comment: Related: [How does the Acolyte have 3 spell slots as a 1st-level spell caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206256/63061).

Comment: Related: [Why do we assume that PHB rules apply to monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181459/23547)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This NPC is built as a stat block version of an Eldritch Knight, not a Wizard. Eldritch Knights use the Wizard spell list, but at 7th level they only have access to 2nd level spells—with the same number and levels of spell slots as this NPC.

Further pointing to Eldritch Knight, the character uses armor, a shield, and martial weaponry with a Multiattack.

Answer (score 21):

### They’re probably based on the Eldritch Knight, but NPCs don’t have to follow the rules for player-characters.

In the question you wrote “an NPC stat block makes no sense”. You go on to explain that it “makes no sense” because it doesn’t strictly adhere to the Spellcasting rules for player-characters. However, there is no rule that requires the DM to create or run NPCs in adherence to the class rules for player-characters. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don’t.

Now, the *Monster Manual* does lead us to expect that monsters with Spellcasting use the general Spellcasting rules in the *Player’s Handbook*:

> A monster with the Spellcasting special trait has a spellcaster level and spell slots, which it uses to cast its spells of 1st level and higher (*as explained in the Player's Handbook*).

This indicates that the general rules for Spellcasting apply to NPCs (because what other rules are there?), but the detailed rules about class levels and spell slots are part of the Spellcasting features found in the player-character class descriptions. See [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206256/62294), and in particular, [Eddymage’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206266/62294) for further discussion and another example monster.

That said, the character you mention is most likely *based* on the Eldritch Knight class, since two of the NPC’s traits are adapted from the Eldritch Knight playable class features War Magic and Weapon Bond. Note, I say *adapted*, because the NPC version of Weapon Bond is much shorter than the player-character version. This is an important distinction: the player-character version of Weapon Bond has additional rules and restrictions that don’t apply to the NPC version, because NPCs don’t have to follow the class-specific rules of player-characters. And as you observed in your own answer to this question, the spell slot distribution given in this NPC’s statblock is consistent with the spell slots available to a typical 7th-level Eldritch Knight.